# Javascript check browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

does anyone have a script for checking for old browsers. It would have to follow this criteria:

1. Allow firefox 3.6 or up
2. Allow Google Chrome 15 and up
3. Allow Safari 5 or up
4. Block IE and opera
5. Block all other browsers

Comment: You should prefer feature detection over browser detection. See, e.g., [Modernirz](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Seconding Sirko for feature detection.  If you want to include names and version numbers, it should only be to offer suggestions if/when you detect the user's browser is lacking a feature you require.

Comment: block IE and Opera ? OMG

Comment: How comes IE9 and Opera 11 is old , but Firefox 3.6 is "new" ? **What is the problem you are actually trying to solve ?** Instead of banning 75%+ of userbase ..

Comment: Just hopping by ... You can go through this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `navigator` object for this and in that you can use `userAgent` property like

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
 //Allow
 }else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') + 7).split(' ')[0]) >= 15){//Chrome
 //Allow
 }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Version') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Version') + 8).split(' ')[0]) >= 5){//Safari
 //Allow
 }else{
 // Block
 }
```

Comment: @JackRenshaw  .. and it is completely useless , since browsers can be masked as any other and you can even turn off javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with with @Sirko. Preferably, you *should* use feature-detection instead. An alternative to to [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) would be jQuery's [`$.support()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) function. It's not *exactly* the same thing, but it may suit your needs.

If you insist on browser-detection, you can write your own script using jQuery's [`$.browser()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) function.

Comment: The problem with that it that some supposedly modern browsers, like the latest version of IE and opera, don't allow JS obfuscating with HTML blocks.

Comment: What? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Just a comment here, $.browser has been removed from jQuery 1.9.0