# I need to know the user's navigator name but i can't

Tags: javascript

I wanna know user's navigator name and alert  it But Both in Firefox and Chrome the alert text is "Netscape" . Here is my javascript code :

```
var app=navigator.appName;
alert(app);
```

Comment: Wrong property. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10257955/447356) how to detect browser name.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with browser detection? FYI, browser detection is **unreliable**. If you are trying to detect the availability of certain features, use feature detection instead (e.g. [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/))

Comment: Try if(window.navigator.appName == "")

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: @VaibhavJain No ... it is also wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to extract this information from `navigator.userAgent` instead. Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Tre8/1/).

Comment: Ok .... But it alerts me a lot of text .... How can i find my browser name ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257810/javascript-check-browser

Comment: All of answers are same :(

Answer (score 0):

The navigator object contains properties such as:

```
appCodeName
appName
appVersion
...
userAgent
vendor
```

and many others.

If you use chrome just type window.navigator in the console and you'll see all available fields.