# Is there a way to disable all browsers exept Firefox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

i have been running into some Problems on my website and now i want to block all browsers exept firefox at least till i fix the issues

Comment: No, there isn't; and more importantly: no, you shouldn't.

Comment: Put a simple message on your website to suggest your audience to use Firefox if they encounter a problem.

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257810/javascript-check-browser